# C# Storing database table rows in Lists

Tags: c#, database

I have a database with various tables and I use various SQL queries to extract the following:-

Table1

```
ID, Surname, Title, Department

1,   Jones,     Mr,    20

1,   Jones,     Mr,    21
```

A person can be a member of many departments.  So the SQL query I do produces multiple rows of the same person (same ID) but with different department ID's.  This information is stored in a list.

I can display this information without problem in a DataGridView object.

I also have another List for Departments, which I populate via a SQL query:-

```
ID,  Name

20,  Accounts

21,  Admin
```

What I am trying to achieve is to combine these two Lists so I end up with something like:-

```
ID, Surname, Title, Department

1,   Jones,     Mr,    Accounts, Admin
```

So, a new third List contains only 1 row per person ID but that row contains the department name not the department ID and also that row contains all of the departments that person is a member of.

Comment: So your first list is something like `List<Person>` and your second is `List<Department>`?

Comment: It is generally desirable to do joins in the RDBMS when they will reduce network traffic, as here by reducing data volume transferred and the number of queries executed. The RDBMS is better equipped to optimize joins (in general).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest do the join in SQL, because it will be more efficient - that's what DataBase is designed to do!

However, if you really want you can use LINQ to Objects. I assumed you have two lists:

```
var people = new List<Person>();
var departments = new List<Department>();
```

both `Person` and `Department` has properties you've written about.

Your query:

```
var query= from p in people
           join d in departments on p.Department equals d.ID
           group d by new { p.ID, p.Surname, p.Title } into g
           select new {
               g.Key.ID,
               g.Key.Surname,
               g.Key.Title,
               Departments = String.Join(", ", g.Select(d => d.Name))
           };
```

And getting results from query to `List` of anonymous type:

```
var result = query.ToList();
```